# Intermittent authentication error while sending mails using Spring using smtp.gmail.com

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails through a Spring app using smtp.gmail.com (port 587). The problem is I am intermittently facing the following error.

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

The error does not appear all the times and mails are sent properly. But sometimes the error appears and mails are not sent. I have set the following to true **https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps**

Following is the configuration

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mail.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailService" class="com.server.service.impl.MailServiceImpl">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    <property name="customMailMessage" ref="customMailMessage" />
</bean>
```

the properties are given below

```
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.port=587
mail.username=******
mail.password=******
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's either an unreliability in Gmail, or it's purposely failing to reduce the rate at which you're sending messages.  You might try turning on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to see if it provides additional information about the failure.  The AuthenticationFailedException usually contains additional information about the failure, but Spring may be hiding that.